# Error in Laravel Accessor while retrieving date in specific format

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel accessor to access value of date field in specific format. But, I am getting error from carbon library of `InvalidArgument`. Below is my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\modules\hrm;

use App\Helper\DateFormat;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Holiday extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $dates = ['off_date'];

    public function setOffDateAttribute($date)
    {
        $this->attributes['off_date'] = DateFormat::convertToDBFormat($date);
    }

    public function getOffDateAttribute($date){
        return DateFormat::convertToUIFormat($date);
    }
}
```

**Helper File**

```
<?php


namespace App\Helper;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class DateFormat
{

    public static function convertToDBFormat($date) {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    public static function convertToUIFormat($date) {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->format('d/m/Y');
    }
}

?>
```

**Model Function**

```
 public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $data = Holiday::find(json_decode($request->get('data'),true)['id']);
        if (empty($data)) {
            return response()->json(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Invalid ID"));
        } else {
            return response()->json(array("status" => "success", "data" => $data));
        }
    }
```

I am getting error from Carbon but I think I am doing something wrong while sending those values, maybe i am not using the laravel accessor feature properly.

**Error:**

```
"message": "Trailing data",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
```

Comment: First off, what are you trying to do when getting this error? Second, what is the full error message? Carbon should be saying more than just `InvalidArgumentException`. Passing null as the second parameter in `createFromFormat` method, for example, gives me a message of `Data Missing` after the exception. Please show us the code where the model is being used and the error is thrown.

Comment: @Criss check updates post

Comment: What is the format of `off_date` field? Is it `Y-m-d H:i:s`? In your example you are not using the date manipulation methods, so my guess is that laravel cannot parse the underlying field with Carbon.

Comment: `protected $dates = ['off_date'];` seems unnecessary since you have your own property accessor and setter

Comment: @Criss yes the format is with time as well because if I don’t use get method then the value returned has hours min and second with all value as 0

Comment: Can you post the full laravel error with backtrace? Might have some more information. Other than that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Criss the format was Y-m-d H:i:s. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Carbon's `->toDateTimeString()` will format the date correctly, saving you from manually having to set the format string.